# Creating a Latex table with text

Tags: tables

How should I tex this for it to become a visually appealing table in Latex? Right now it looks like this. However I am finding it difficult to find out how to make the "abbrivation" and "source" be centered. Also, is it possible to make the font smaller, so that the table is smaller?

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{tblr}{ Q[l,b,wd=6cm] Q[b] Q[b] }
\toprule
Variables                             & Abbrevation & Source \\ 
\midrule
CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita). This is our dependent variable. It is a proxy of environmental degradation. & co2  & WDI    \\

GDP per capita (constant 2015 US\$). It is used as an independent variable.      & gdp\_pc         & WDI    \\ 

Energy use (kg of oil equivalent per capita). It is used as an independent variable.   & energy    & WDI    \\ 

Gender parity index (GPI), school enrollment, primary and secondary (gross). It is used as an independent variable.    & gpi       & WDI    \\ 

Labor force participation rate,female (\% of female population ages 15+). It is used as an independent variable.        & f\_labor\_15        & WDI    \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.stack.exchange community.

Comment: Without any code, that shows, what you've already tried and what the problems are, this looks like a do-it-for-me question. So I would just say: Use e.g. `m`-columns (see the `array` package) or `X`-columns of `tabularray`. And please have a look at other questions. We have a lot of questions about making such tables.

Answer (score 2):

What is visually appealing varies a lot amongst individuals. I would probably use the `tabularray` package and style the table using the `booktabs` package (here used as library):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{ Q[l,b,wd=4cm] Q[b] Q[b] }
\toprule
Variables                             & Abbrevation & Source \\ 
\midrule
CO2 emission (metric tons per capita) & co2         & WDI    \\
Second                                & aaa         & bbb    \\ 
Third                                 & ccc         & ddd    \\ 
Fourth                                & fff         & ggg    \\ 
Fifth                                 & hhh         & iii    \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With changing the `b` option in the column definitions to `m`, the cell contents will be vertically aligned around the center. As for reducing the font size or styling the text, there are several options depending on what you want to style, only parts of the text or whole columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{ Q[l,m,wd=4cm] Q[m,font=\footnotesize] Q[m] }
\toprule
Variables                             & Abbrevation & Source \\ 
\midrule
CO2 emission {\footnotesize(\textbf{metric tons} per capita)} 
                                      & co2         & WDI    \\
Second                                & aaa         & bbb    \\ 
Third                                 & ccc         & ddd    \\ 
Fourth                                & fff         & ggg    \\ 
Fifth                                 & hhh         & iii    \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. ....

Comment: Maybe, like suggested in the comments above, an `X` column would also do for the first column.

Comment: This has been very helpful!

Comment: @AstridLarsen Does my edit help you? It depends what you want to achieve. You could of course also place the whole `tblr` environment inside a group (using surrounding `{}`) and add the commands to change the font directly before `\begin{tblr}` to style the whole table ...

Comment: It has been quite helpful! I've added a few things myself, so now I am very happy with how the table is looking.

Answer (score 1):

Only small, mostly off-topic variation of the second example in @Jasper Habicht answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}          % added
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % added
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[j,m] Q[l] Q[l] @{}}, % <---
             }
    \toprule
Variables   & Abbreviation & Source \\
    \midrule
\ce{CO2} emissions (metric tons per capita). This is our dependent variable. It is a proxy of environmental degradation.
            & \ce{CO2}      & WDI    \\

GDP per capita (constant 2015 US\$). It is used as an independent variable.      
            & gdp\_pc       & WDI    \\

Energy use (kg of oil equivalent per capita). It is used as an independent variable.   
            & energy        & WDI    \\
Gender parity index (GPI), school enrollment, primary and secondary (gross). It is used as an independent variable.    
            & gpi           & WDI   \\
Labor force participation rate,female (\% of female population ages 15+). It is used as an independent variable.        
            & f\_labor\_15  & WDI    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```